# Which is faster for small web projects - MySQL or Oracle?

Tags: mysql, oracle, performance

Which is generally faster for small web projects - MySQL or Oracle?

Please provide some proof (benchmarks or any other) of your opinion.

Comment: What's your definition of "small"? Few users, few developers, few code? Regardless, there are typically other factors that outweigh performance considerations. Especially if they can be solved by a 3-digit hardware investment.

Comment: What I mean is that there is around 10 tables in the database and they will contain around 1000 rows perhaps. The database should rather be fast at selecting than inserting.

Comment: That's a *very* small dataset. The fastest solution there might be an in-memory database. For Java I'd suggest [H2](http://h2database.com/), when it comes to speed

Comment: What's your definition of 'fast'.

Comment: You need to give some idea of concurrent workload. Are you talking 100 hits a second or a million ? Are you talking Java, Ruby, PHP, whatever as the client. If the data is fixed, with that small data volume, it can be cached entirely in an application layer, so the underlying DB makes no difference. Also MySQL has a dozen storage engines which may offer different speeeds. 1000 rows each containing a 250Mb Video stream would also be massively different from a 1000 rows of 100 bytes each.

Answer (score 8):

In >90% of cases MySQL. Since most simple websites have simple key-value with some very limited relations and no or limited need for transactions.

Oracle really comes to its right with complicated datamodels requiring tuned SQL queries and high transaction counts.

Comment: is there any actual benchmarking proof that fir "simple key value" stuff Oracle is measurably slower?

Comment: The cost of creating a connection in MySQL is relatively low. In  small web projects where users browse fast between pages, this might be a benefit.

Comment: I based this on benchmarking I did long ago between MySQL, Postgresql and Oracle. I used at that time ISAM tables and found them to be very fast, but the lack of transactions and (relatively) poor performance on joins were the minusses. Oracle scales much better than either one, but the domain needed to be complaicated and big enough to show it. In the end we decided on postgresql as it was best for our intended purpose. In the mean time a lot of water has passed under the bridge and I really need to redo this test.

Answer (score 8):

For **small** web projects it doesn't matter. They are both fast enough.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL is free and generally great for small projects. Oracle costs you some bills. That's enough for me. You might also consider Postgre for small web projects. Possibly related: [When to choose Oracle over MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788854/when-to-choose-oracle-over-mysql)

Comment: The Oracle XE is also free for dataset < 2Gb, which is usually just fine for small websites. But why bother with the overhead if you do not need it?

Comment: @PeterTillemans - actually the XE license permits 4GB of user data

Answer (score 2):

yes probably MySQL.
For small projects I think [SQLLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is also a good option

Comment: SQLite doesn't support pretty much anything a real database needs (loops? triggers? concurrency???) It is OK to store configuration or data for single-threaded program. But it's not strictly speaking a database server - merely a file store with SQL-ish API

Answer (score 1):

Small web projects are dominated by engineering cost, so I guess you mean installation time. MySQL can be installed faster. And of course both are a bad idea from engineering time pov. A small web project should be able to do without a RDBMS (e.g. Seaside with Sandstone persistence).

In a commercial setting it is a question with little value. There the important thing is to be able to do many projects, and the scalability and interoperability  range you want to achieve. That depends on the market you want to be in, the qualifications of the people you work with.

Answer (score 1):

For a small project there should be no real difference.
I'd suggest that you consider:

- speed of installation (Mysql is easier to install)
- features (Oracle has way more features in some areas)
- existing SQL knowledge for the DBMSes (SQL differs between Mysql and oracle)

etc.

Depending on your needs the answer may be oracle or mysql.